# Need help to get correct regex format for usernames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need help getting the regex format of my usernames correct. It suppose to require 3 letters in it and allow no spaces or `_`. I think I'm on the right track so far with this:

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /([^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^a-zA-Z]*){3,}/
```

This allows spaces though and I'm not sure if this is correct in general. What corrections do I need for this regex to get rid of the ability to use spaces or `_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean it has to be all letters, it's just:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$/
```

Otherwise, use a lookahead:

```
/^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){3})[allowed characters here]+$/
```

Comment: Whoops, I forgot the allowing of numbers parts. How would I have it require at least 3 letters, no spaces or underscores and allow numbers?

Comment: @LearningRoR: See update, you can specify any set of characters. (Numbers would be `a-zA-Z0-9`.)

Comment: So this: `/^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){3})[a-zA-z0-9]+$/`

Comment: @LearningRoR: The `A-z` should be `A-Z`, but yes :)